# Intergrating Zend Framework 2 and Propel

Tags: propel, zend-framework2

I've searched far and wide on how to intergrate propel and Zend Framework 2 however I haven't been able to come up with a solution yet.

Here is what I have so far.

Installed ZF2 Skeleton Directory
Inserted Sample Album Table Data from ZF site

My Folder Structure looks like this

```
--Vendor
----Propel
------album
--------autoload_classmap.php
--------models
----------map
----------om
----------Album.php
----------AlbumPeer.php
----------AlbumQuery.php
------config
--------module.config.php
------Module.php
------autoload_classmap.php
```

The album/autoload_classmap.php looks like this

```
//vendor/Propel/album/autoload_classmap.php
<?php
// Generated by ZF2's ./bin/classmap_generator.php
return array(
    'AlbumTableMap'  => __DIR__ . '/models/map/AlbumTableMap.php',
    'BaseAlbumPeer'  => __DIR__ . '/models/om/BaseAlbumPeer.php',
    'BaseAlbumQuery' => __DIR__ . '/models/om/BaseAlbumQuery.php',
    'BaseAlbum'      => __DIR__ . '/models/om/BaseAlbum.php',
    'Album'          => __DIR__ . '/models/Album.php',
    'AlbumPeer'      => __DIR__ . '/models/AlbumPeer.php',
    'AlbumQuery'     => __DIR__ . '/models/AlbumQuery.php',
);
```

Here is the module.config.php

```
//vendor/Propel/config/module.config.php
<?php
return array();
```

Here is the Propel/autoload_classmap.php

```
//vendor/Propel/autoload_classmap.php

<?php
// Generated by ZF2's ./bin/classmap_generator.php
return array(
    'Propel'                                              => __DIR__ . '/runtime/lib/Propel.php',
);
```

and finally the Model.php file

```
    //vendor/Propel/Module.php
<?php

namespace Propel;

class Module
{

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\ClassMapAutoloader' => array(
                __DIR__ . '/autoload_classmap.php',
                __DIR__ . '/album/autoload_classmap.php'
            )
        );
    }

    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }
}
```

For the **sake of simplicity in this example** I put the following code into my Controller.

```
//module/Application/src/Application/Controller/IndexController.php
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class IndexController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $q = new \Propel\Album();
        $q->setArtist('The Who');
        $q->setTitle('Tommy');
        $q->save();

        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

The error I get is

```
 Class 'Propel\\Album' not found
```

The sources I used to get to this point were

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/propel-users/zend/propel-users/lsHs-jjxp68/LDrQjzik6gAJ
https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=forums&srcid=MDU2NDIxODQyNDc0MDMyNjQ3NzUBMDY3ODcxMTYzMzg0MDA4OTU0MzgBeFpDZUM1WTZqMThKATQBAXYy
[Adding Vendor Specific Module To Zend Framework 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12600464/adding-vendor-specific-module-to-zend-framework-2-0)

Comment: I wrote this blog post which i believe answers this question: http://4zend.com/integrate-propel-orm-with-zend-framework-2/ Hope this works out for you. UPDATE: I turned this into a working module. You can browse it on github and see how it's done or just install it using Composer.

Answer (score 2):

If you didn't set namespace in your XML schema, your classes should be accessible in the root namespace, so as \Album for example. If you want to have some other namespace, you shoud define it in database tag of your XML schema. And you should not use Propel namespace anyway as it is reserved for Propel itself. Your generated classes should be long to the namespace of your project.

Answer (score 0):

`\Propel\Album` is not being found because the class map specifies `Album` as the class name.

I'm guessing if you added the line: `namespace Propel;` to each of those Propel related files the classmap generator would put the correct class names. Of course then you would need update an class names in the code that are affected.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Adding the name space to each is rather unreasonable though.  There has to be a better way to implement propel to ZF2

Comment: You're welcome - I'm sure someone would have come across this before. Does the new Album class work if you use new \Album()? I've never used much of Propel but it seems to support namespaces - http://www.propelorm.org/cookbook/namespaces.html

Comment: Great suggestions however that did not work.  I was able to pull a function from the Vendor/Propel/Module.php class using.  `code` echo \Propel\Module::MYCONSTANT;

Comment: I typed function.  I meant Constant.  I was able to pull a _Constant_ from the Vendor/Propel/Module.php

Comment: That works because the Module class exists under the Propel namespace but the additional Propel files are not within the Propel namespace. If you can get your files under the Propel namespace (using that link) then recreate the class map it should work. One thing to understand is that the configuration provided by a module does not have to be related to that module. Looking at the contents of the class map you’ll see there is no mention of Propel apart from the fact it lives in the Propel directory.

Comment: I guess something is wrong with the autoloader.  If I force a require('/vendor/Propel/album/models/Album.php'); on my .phtml file (and remove the Extends) I am able to pull a function from Album.php file.  However at this point I am not really doing anything ZF like and I am really lost to what the real problem is.